# lambda monitoring using aws quicksight

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, monitoring, amazon-quicksight

i have few lambdas that use different other services like SSM, athena, dynamodb, s3, SQS, SNS for my process. i am almost done with all my development and would love to monitor it visually. I use X-ray and cloud watch as my regular log monitoring and analysis. I feel cloud watch dashboards is not so efficient way to visualize my stuff with multiple services. So i did a lambda that pulls trace data from my X-ray traces and outputs a nested json file something like below.

```
[
{
    "id": "4707a33e472",
    "name": "test-lambda",
    "start_time": 1524714634.098,
    "end_time": 1524714672.046,
    "parent_id": "1b9122bc",
    "aws": {
        "function_arn": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:9684596:function:test-lambda",
        "resource_names": [
            "test-lambda"
        ],
        "account_id": "9684596"
    },
    "trace_id": "1-5ae14c88-41dca52ccec8c7d",
    "origin": "AWS::Lambda::Function",
    "subsegments": [
        {
            "id": "ab6420197c",
            "name": "S3",
            "start_time": 1524714671.7148032,
            "end_time": 1524714671.8333395,
            "http": {
                "response": {
                    "status": 200
                }
            },
            "aws": {
                "id_2": "No9Gemg5b9Y2XREorBG+6a1KLXX7S6O3HtPZ3f6vUuU5F1dQE0nIE1WmwmRRHIqCjI=",
                "operation": "DeleteObjects",
                "region": "us-east-1",
                "request_id": "E2709BB91B8"
            },
            "namespace": "aws"
        },
        {
            "id": "370e11d6d",
            "name": "SSM",
            "start_time": 1524714634.0991564,
            "end_time": 1524714634.194922,
            "http": {
                "response": {
                    "status": 200
                }
            },
            "aws": {
                "operation": "GetParameter",
                "region": "us-east-1",
                "request_id": "f901ed67-4904-bde0-f9ad15cc558b"
            },
            "namespace": "aws"
        },
        {
            "id": "8423bf21354",
            "name": "DynamoDB",
            "start_time": 1524714671.9744427,
            "end_time": 1524714671.981935,
            "http": {
                "response": {
                    "status": 200
                }
            },
            "aws": {
                "operation": "UpdateItem",
                "region": "us-east-1",
                "request_id": "3AHBI44JRJ2UJ72V88CJPV5L4JVV4K6Q9ASUAAJG",
                "table_name": "test-dynamodb",
                "resource_names": [
                    "test-dynamodb"
                ]
            },
```

I only posted the first few line of x-ray trace json output, but it's pretty large to post here. AWS quicksight doesn't support nested json, my question is, is there a way to visualize all my lambdas in a better way using quicksight. I am not allowed to use other third party monitoring systems. Need help with this